# What is the difference between using PIXI.Sprite.fromImage and PIXI.loader.resources?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

The first 3 lines of code doesn't work while the last 2 lines correctly displayed the image. What is wrong with the first one and what is the difference between the two ways of displaying sprites?

```
let plot = new PIXI.Sprite(
    PIXI.loader.resources["assets/plot/images/main.png"].texture);
this.plotContainer.stage.addChild(plot);

let plot2 = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("assets/plot/images/main.png");
this.plotContainer.stage.addChild(plot2);
```

EDIT:
Actually, the image only shows up when I combine the two together. When only the first 3 lines are run, only a black screen shows up. When the last two lines are run, only the original background shows up.

Comment: Where are you getting the first version from?

Comment: https://github.com/kittykatattack/learningPixi#introduction, unless I didn't copy or understand it correctly.

Comment: This works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/63udhg10/ so the error must be in your implementation. You *are* adding that png to the loader, right?

Comment: I don't see the sprite from the link.

Comment: My code doesn't display the sprite but successfully loads it. Check the console output.

Comment: I updated my fiddle. It now does display the image.

Comment: I looked at the console. There are differences between my object and yours. The main difference I see is that the imageURL in texture/baseTexture is null in mine while it has the correct url in yours. I don't understand why that is since my code is basically yours. I loaded the image in the line before:         `PIXI.loader.add("assets/plot/images/main.png");`

Comment: If you want help with your code, post it in full. Still, in case it isn't clear: loading an image doesn't happen instantly; this is no trouble for the second version, the first version however must be used in a way that doesn't trip over that fact.

Comment: I got it. I think the problem was that the loader didn't finish loading the texture before I used it to create the Sprite. Thanks for your help!